# How well can you approximate $\mathbb{Z}$ using product of first $t$ numbers?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a bound on how well you can (additive) approximate any natural number as the product of , say, first $10$ numbers - $\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$? By product, I mean just a single product, no additions allowed.

For example, using just the products of $\{1,2\}$, you can incur arbitrarily large errors. For example, any additive error $2^{\delta}$ can be achieved by considering the number $2^{1+\delta} + 2^{\delta}$. The best additive approximation is $2^{1+\delta}$ or $2^{2+\delta}$, both incurring the error $2^{\delta}$.

However, this argument is not clear to me when you consider the product of $\{1,2,3\}$. Similar arguments can be made for just $2$ and $3$ but when we consider approximations of form $2^x3^y$, it becomes unclear to me.

Intuitively, I feel like this representation is not dense enough and should incur unbounded error in general for any $t$, but I do not know how to show it.

Comment: For distinct primes $p,q$ and $x.y>0$, what's the best product approximation you can get to $$p^xq^y(1+\frac{1}{pq})?$$

Comment: My intuition tells me the answer should involve the number $p\,\mathrm{lcm}[1, 2, \ldots t]$ with $p>t$ prime, but I'm not sure how to put that together into an answer.

Comment: @user469053 maybe $p^{x-1}q^{y-1}$? I'm not sure how to show this.